# Plotting an x-y grid of connected points in Python

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

a Python newbie here!

I'm hoping you can help. I am trying to create a dataframe that contains the following columns:

- index (a unique sequential number)
- origin coordinate (in the format (x, y))
- destination coordinate (same format)
- connected (binary 0/1) - indicates whether the origin and destination are connected or not

I'm doing this because I am trying to create a grid using these coordinates that show each coordinate as a dot, and each connection as a line segment.

Here's my mocked up attempt:

```
import pandas as pd
origin = [(0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2),
          (0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2),
          (0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2),
          (0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2),
          (0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2),
          (0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2),
          (0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2),
          (0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2),
          (0,0), (0,1), (0,2), (1,0), (1,1), (1,2), (2,0), (2,1), (2,2)]
destination = [(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),(0,0),
               (0,1),(0,1),(0,1),(0,1),(0,1),(0,1),(0,1),(0,1),(0,1),
               (0,2),(0,2),(0,2),(0,2),(0,2),(0,2),(0,2),(0,2),(0,2),
               (1,0),(1,0),(1,0),(1,0),(1,0),(1,0),(1,0),(1,0),(1,0),
               (1,1),(1,1),(1,1),(1,1),(1,1),(1,1),(1,1),(1,1),(1,1),
               (1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(1,2),
               (2,0),(2,0),(2,0),(2,0),(2,0),(2,0),(2,0),(2,0),(2,0),
               (2,1),(2,1),(2,1),(2,1),(2,1),(2,1),(2,1),(2,1),(2,1),
               (2,2),(2,2),(2,2),(2,2),(2,2),(2,2),(2,2),(2,2),(2,2)]
connected = np.zeros(81)
network = pd.DataFrame({'origin': origin, 'destination': destination, 'connected': connected})
for ind in network.index:
    if network['origin'][ind] == network['destination'][ind]:
        network['connected'][ind] = 0
    else:
        network['connected'][ind] = np.random.randint(0,2)
```

I have several questions:

1. How do I plot these points and connections, using pyplot?
2. My code connects points randomly, whether they are neighbouring or not, but I need them to only connect randomly if they are diagonally or orthogonally adjacent (so (0,0) cannot connect to (2,1) for example) . How do I do that?
3. Is there a better/more elegant way of presenting this data, instead of the dataframe of 3 columns I have shared here?
4. My grid will be a 25x25 grid and so the coordinates list will be much longer, how can I auto-generate these coordinates rather than writing them out manually?

Thank you in advance, I really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

This is how you connect them:

```
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
assert len(origin) == len(destination)
for i in range(len(origin)):
    plt.plot(origin[i], destination[i])
plt.show()
```

which gives

[image]